# No audio on Ubuntu 23.04 fresh install

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 23.04, pipewire

I have just installed ubuntu 23.04 on my hp 15 fc00xx laptop. The sound would not work at all, there is only 'Dummy Output' in the settings. I have read about 100 posts and have tried everything. But the audio just won't work. Here are the outputs of some commands relevant to this issue:

```
uname -r

6.2.0-20-generic
```

```
sudo lspci

s00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe Root Complex (rev 02)
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe GPP Bridge (rev 02)
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe GPP Bridge (rev 02)
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h PCIe Dummy Host Bridge (rev 02)
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h Internal PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h-19h Internal PCIe GPP Bridge
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1724
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1725
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1726
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1727
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1728
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1729
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 172a
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 172b
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5017 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b85b
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mendocino (rev c2)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1503
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1504
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 6f)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
04:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1505
```

```
inxi -SMA

System:
  Host: Krish Kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME
    v: 44.0 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Laptop 15-fc0xxx v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8B2F v: 52.40 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: F.07 date: 03/13/2023
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: snd_pci_acp6x
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-20-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
```

```
aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm having a similar problem, from time to time when i turn on my laptop there is no audio, the system is slow and some apps crash, then i turn it off and on again and everything works fine. IDK what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem, I solved it.

Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install pipewire-alsa
```

See:
https://wiki.archlinuxcn.org/wiki/PipeWire